# Javascript - how do i get a gradual list of HEX colors between 2 HEX colors?

Tags: javascript, css, colors, hex

If i have 2 colors:

**#ffcc00 and #334455**

how do i get all the #hex colors between these two colors, gradually sorted?

Comment: Try [RainbowVis](https://github.com/anomal/RainbowVis-JS) library.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown You should formulate that suggestion as an answer

Comment: @fvu yeah I *could* but unfortunately I'm out of time right now =/

Comment: JS version of a HSV gradient http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593832/how-to-interpolate-hue-values-in-hsv-colour-space

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try this tool:

http://www.colorhexa.com/ffcc00-to-334455

Though it only gives you 11 values between the ones you enter

Comment: [Here](http://www.workwithcolor.com/mm-color-blender-01.htm?cp=FFCC00&ch=48-100-50&cp2=334455&ch2=210-25-27&im=3&cm=1) is another color blender